# JQuery fadeIn/fadeOut works on first load but not on reload

Tags: jquery, ios, fadein, fadeout

The page I'm working on is http://technimedinc.com/index_fb.html

The relevant jQuery code is below:

```
<script>
$('<img src="images/learn_more_on.png"/>');

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#hb1_off").delay(3000).fadeOut(1000).delay(2000).fadeIn(1000);
    $("#hb2_off").delay(6000).fadeOut(1000).delay(2000).fadeIn(1000);
    $("#hb3_off").delay(9000).fadeOut(1000).delay(2000).fadeIn(1000);
});

$("#hb1").hover(function(){
    $("#hb1_off").fadeOut("fast");
}, function() {
    $("#hb1_off").fadeIn("fast");
});

$("#hb2").hover(function(){
    $("#hb2_off").fadeOut("fast");
}, function() {
    $("#hb2_off").fadeIn("fast");
});

$("#hb3").hover(function(){
    $("#hb3_off").fadeOut("fast");
}, function() {
    $("#hb3_off").fadeIn("fast");
});
</script>
```

The problem I'm having is that if I shift-reload the page (to refresh CSS and other linked files), everything seems to work fine. The timed fadeOut and fadeIns work, as do the hovers. However, if I reload the page, everything stops working.

There is a Facebook box on the page, which may be a factor. I switched to loading jQuery locally, but that didn't help the issue.

Finally, the fadeIn and fadeOut on document ready isn't working on iOS at all. (I know the hover won't work, obviously).

If someone could point me in the right direction, I would appreciated it. I have spent the better part of two days scouring these questions and answers but haven't been able to solve this on my own.

Comment: (And yes, the source code is a mess...inherited a table-based site.)

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you change the code to this? I have included your `hover` handlers in your `(document).ready()` handler by moving the close parens to the end of the code snippet.

```
<script>
$('<img src="images/learn_more_on.png"/>');

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#hb1_off").delay(3000).fadeOut(1000).delay(2000).fadeIn(1000);
$("#hb2_off").delay(6000).fadeOut(1000).delay(2000).fadeIn(1000);
$("#hb3_off").delay(9000).fadeOut(1000).delay(2000).fadeIn(1000);


$("#hb1").hover(function(){
$("#hb1_off").fadeOut("fast");
}, function() {
$("#hb1_off").fadeIn("fast");
});

$("#hb2").hover(function(){
$("#hb2_off").fadeOut("fast");
}, function() {
$("#hb2_off").fadeIn("fast");
});

$("#hb3").hover(function(){
$("#hb3_off").fadeOut("fast");
}, function() {
$("#hb3_off").fadeIn("fast");
});

});

</script>
```

Alternatively, try binding your animations to $('#homecontent').load(function(){//animations here//})

Comment: Is that a question or a solution?   Please be thorough and don't make the reader guess what you did.

Comment: @JasperMogg Thanks for the answer, I came into the office today and lo and behold, the same code I had yesterday is working. I have no idea why, but I'm not complaining. It's even working on iOS! Thanks for your help, though. If the problem resurfaces, I'll add onto this thread.

Comment: @David Portela Glad to hear it mate :-) Just a suggestion btw - when I load your page, the green circles appear briefly on load before disappearing. Perhaps you could set the CSS to visibility:hidden until you want to show them - that way they wouldn't flicker like that.